# Is it possible to limit AWS Account access from corporate devices only

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to ensure that AWS accounts that have been created by an organisation cannot be logged in to from devices that are not part of the corporate infrastructure?

I am struggling to understand how to avoid the situation where accounts are accessed from potentially unmanaged/less secure devices outside the control of the organisation.

Comment: Are you talking about a human logging into the AWS control plane / console from a web browser inside your corporate network, or a web browser logging into a resource such as a web application? If you can be more precise about what you're trying to achieve we might be able to help.

Comment: Personally, I would handle this problem at my corporate SAML Identity Provider rather than AWS. Microsoft AzureAD has Conditional Access policies for this kind of thing. Then, setup AWS Single Sign On federated to AzureAD identity provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of IAM roles, ActiveDirectory and Corporate Firewall to limit the access. You can have an ActiveDirectory group with users from your company only that can access AWS only through Corporate VPN and are assigned IAM roles based on the corporate permissions. I assume that the corporate firewall can be accessed only from corporate hardware.